# serve static files from Django Docker to nginx

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I'm dockerizing Django application but static files are not being served.

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_my_project')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_cdn', 'static_root')
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: "originor-nginx"
    ports:
      - "10080:80"
      - "10443:43"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - originor_static_volume:/app/static_cdn/static_root
      - originor_media_volume:/app/static_cdn/media_root
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: "originor-web"
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "./start.sh"]
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - originor_static_volume:/app/static_cdn/static_root
      - originor_media_volume:/app/static_cdn/media_root
    ports:
      - "9010:9010"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:11
    container_name: "originor-postgres-schema"
    volumes:
      - originor_database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: "originor_pgadmin"
    volumes:
      - originor_pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin

volumes:
  originor_database:
  originor_static_volume:
  originor_media_volume:
  originor_pgadmin:
```

and **nginx.conf**

```
error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf;
proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;

upstream dweb {
    ip_hash;
    server web:9010 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 10080;
    server_name localhost;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log combined;

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /app/static_cdn/static_root/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /app/static_cdn/media_root/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://dweb/;
    }
}
```

But on access `/admin/` in browser, it consoles

```
f032d416bce1_originor-web | Not Found: /static/admin/css/login.css
f032d416bce1_originor-web | Not Found: /static/admin/css/responsive.css
f032d416bce1_originor-web | Not Found: /static/admin/css/base.css
f032d416bce1_originor-web | Not Found: /static/admin/css/base.css
```

I can verify the files there in `/app/static_cdn/static_root` directory by executing

```
docker exec -it <container_id> ls -la /app/static_cdn/static_root
```

> Edit 2: `docker logs <container>`

```
wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for db:5432
wait-for-it.sh: db:5432 is available after 0 seconds
--: Starting application build


--: Creating migration
No changes detected
------: makemigrations complete


--: Running migration
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
------: migrate complete


--: load initial user data


--: load initial oauth app data


--: Running collectstatic

0 static files copied to '/app/static_cdn/static_root', 119 unmodified.
------: collectstatic complete


--: Starting Gunicorn.
[2019-01-11 13:26:47 +0000] [21] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2019-01-11 13:26:47 +0000] [21] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:9010 (21)
[2019-01-11 13:26:47 +0000] [21] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-01-11 13:26:47 +0000] [23] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 23
[2019-01-11 13:26:47 +0000] [24] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 24
[2019-01-11 13:26:47 +0000] [25] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 25
Not Found: /static/admin/css/fonts.css
```

> Edit 3: nginx log

While running `docker-compose up` it gives the following log

[image]

But running `docker logs originor-nginx` it gives nothing

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your 'web' initialization you must call `manage.py collectstatic` to put static files of application in your volume. More info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

UPD:
nginx conf for uwsgi proxy:

```
location / {
    uwsgi_pass uwsgi://web:9010;
    include uwsgi_params;
 }
```

Comment: That is being run in **start.sh**, the script which is run by **command**  in **web**.

Comment: Wait, `alias originor_static_volume` in nginx conf? Maybe `alias /app/static_cdn/static_root/` ?

Comment: No, Actually it seems **nginx** server is not listening. Because nginx port **10080** from browser is not loading website where as **9010** port is accessible on which **web** is working.

Comment: There is no file in the `/var/log` directory of the web container.

Comment: I have updated answer, try conf uwsgi pass. To see nginx logs: `docker logs <container name>`

Comment: Still no luck. Added the log to the question. Can it be due to `nginx:alpine`?

Comment: Tried with `nginx:latest` image also. Still not accessible on port **10080**. Can you verify if the nginx config are correct or not? Should it be listening to port **10080** or not? Also, I want to expose only port through nginx, and block the port on which application is running. ie., **9010** in my case.

Comment: Update question with `nginx` log. There is no log not even in the `docker-compose up` console.